# Advice about statictics that running on my home page

Tags: database, web-deployment

I am making a sport site and I would like to know, will be negative for server if I have on home page, let's say 15 small modules that loading statistics from database? All those queries loads most 16 lines of results each one, not something big. I need your advice on this! Thank you!

Comment: a) this doesn't tell me what language, what types of modules, what types of queries etc. b) the answer to this is highly subjective to your own site, and your own performance tests and definitions of "negative for [the] server"

Comment: This site is based on Joomla. Modules contain JDatabase queries and they load some tables like, top five scorers, which is the next match, rating for some players, league's teams rating. Things like that. Also, I own the site not the server. I just would like to know, cause it would be nice my site not to be heavy, nor for server nor for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of your platform, database interaction is among the most problematic bottlenecks for website performance. Your strategy for data retrieval should always be to minimize database queries, optimize those database queries that you do run and cache the results for as long as is reasonable.

Although you say only a few rows are returned by your queries, that doesn't indicate the cost of the query. Depending on a number of factors (e.g. number rows, data distribution, proper database indexing, number of joins, etc) the cost of those queries may still be considerable and negatively impact the performance of your website.